Why `=floor((189-0.9*201)/(0.9))` is 8?
Why =floor((189-0.9*201)/(0.9)) is 8 ?
Correct answer is 9

This has lead to huge problem and hours of debugging and head scratching
As you can see, this is can lead to big accumulated error.

Why does it happen ?
How to prevent such thing in Google Sheet ?


Why is it tagged Excel if it's about Google Sheets?

That's because Google Sheet runs in Javascript.
The Javascript code:
Math.floor(((189-0.9*201)/(0.9)))
yields also 8.
That is because
(((189-0.9*201)/(0.9))) is 8.999999999999993 due to floating error precision.
Hence, you can do like this:
=floor(round((189-0.9*201)/(0.9), 9))

